# Username check prior to form submission - JQUERY/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have been using this example: http://youhack.me/2010/05/04/username-availability-check-in-registration-form-using-jqueryphp/ to create a form (takes user to confirmation page before adding to database - easy part which comes after)..however i would like it to check whether a username is available or not prior to submitting the form. I cannot for the life of me figure out what im doing wrong with it :P

MY jquery/AJAX is below: (the PHP file it calls works fine i have no need to put it on here)

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".form").submit(function()
        { 
            var username = $(".userID").val();

            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",
                url: "id_check.php",  
                data: "userID="+ username,  
                success: function(response){

                    if(response=="NO"){
                        alert("no");    
                    }
                    else if(response=="YES"){   
                        alert("yes");
                    }
                }

            });

            return false; //if i take this line out it submits either way

        });

    });
```

I know the php works because the correct alert pops up when a username is taken or not, but i cannot get it to submit the form when the response is YES without it submitting when the response is also NO. I have tried many different things (including $(form).submit() and various returns etc within the IF statements) but to no avail.

I basically need it to submit when the name is not taken and to NOT submit when it is...any help is greatly appreciated!! (i think ive included all information necessary to potentially fix it haha)

Alan

Comment: possible duplicate of [.submit() not working correctly, unbind() helps but comes with a side affect :P](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688532/submit-not-working-correctly-unbind-helps-but-comes-with-a-side-affect-p)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (look at the comments):

```
    $(".form").submit(function(e)
    { 
        var username = $(".userID").val();
        //cache the current form 
        var form = this;
        //check if the event is started by the user or by your success function
        //if it's triggered by the user, check for the username
        if (e.originalEvent !== undefined){
          $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",
            url: "id_check.php",  
            data: "userID="+ username,  
            success: function(response){

                if(response=="NO"){
                    alert("no");    
                }
                else if(response=="YES"){   
                    //submit the form you have cached
                    $(form).submit();
                    alert("yes");
                }
            }

          });

        //This is to prevent the form from submitting when you click the submit button
        return false; //if i take this line out it submits either way
        }


    });
```

Comment: thanks for the response. i tried what you amended and it puts it into a loop - the alert "yes" kept popping up when submit button is clicked...

Comment: @AlanWareham yes of course because it retriggers the form, i modified my answer to take account of that, basically you check if the event is generated by the user or by the call

Comment: this stopped it from looping and calling the form over and over, and the right messages still display but the form does not submit in either case still.

Answer (score 0):

The return false will not allow the button to submit and this also because the return false statement runs before the ajax finish it's call. So i think you will need to have a hidden button that you will call it's submit when the response == "YES".

Comment: so a hidden button that submits the same form, but is only called when the response is yes like you said?

Comment: also the $(".form") will be a normal input type button that it's click will decide if you fire the submit button or not.