# .submit() not working correctly, unbind() helps but comes with a side affect

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit

Will keep it short and sweet:

- form designed to create a new user if username is available (goes to a confirm page actually)
- form is stopped and error message displayed if name is not available
- the PHP works fine and the form is stopped when name is taken however it takes 2 clicks of the submit when a valid username is entered, first click does nothing second click submits the form fine, so it all works apart from having to click twice

Any help in being able to submit the form straight away would help me a great deal :)

The code as it is works, apart from when username is available it does not submit, the line that is commented out allows it to submit but as mentioned before only after second click of submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$(".f_create").submit(function()
{ 

    var username = $(".userID").val();

    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",
      url: "id_check.php",  
      data: "userID="+ username,  
      success: function(response){

        if(response=="NO"){
            $('.l_userID').append('<label class="format" style="color:blue">Nope</label>');   
        }
        else if(response=="YES"){   
            // $(".f_create").unbind();  ..... submits the form but only on second click of submit button
            $(".f_create").submit();

        }

      }

    });

    return false; 

});

});
```

Comment: In this scenario it makes sense to perform the ajax call synchronously.

Comment: @AlanWareham You seem to have already asked this question. Don't duplicate questions. Upvote useful answers, and use the **[`Accept answer`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110460/how-to-improve-accept-rate-in-stack-overflow)** feature if an answer is fully correct. This will help future readers to find the right solution more quickly.

Comment: ah right my apologies. thanks rob.

Answer (score 3):

You can define an optional parameter at your submit function. When you manually trigger the `submit` method again, pass a parameter, `true` to submit the real form.

```
$(".f_create").submit(function(e, explicitSubmit){ 
    if (explicitsubmit) {
         //If the flag is defined, cancel function.
         return; //<-- Return. Form will be "normally" submitted.
    } else {
        // By default, prevent a submission
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    var username = $(".userID").val();

    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",
      url: "id_check.php",  
      data: "userID="+ username,  
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == "NO") {
            $('.l_userID').append('<label class="format" style="color:blue">Nope</label>');   
        }
        else if (response == "YES") {
            $(".f_create").trigger("submit", [/* explicitSubmit */true]);

        }
      }
    });
});
```